# Gif или спрайт для анимации на Android

Tags: android, анимация, canvas, webgl

Встал вопрос о том, как лучше сделать анимацию на Android. Gif или спрайтом, какие плюсы и минусы обоих подходов. Возможно есть другие варианты.

Мы хотим сделать анимацию flat-персонажа. 
Похожую на эту [работу](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/644659/screenshots/1958383/monster_dribble.gif)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Формат gif**

---

**Минусы:**

1) Не поддерживает прозрачность.
2) Нельзя остановить анимацию в нужный момент.

**Плюсы:**

Не надо заморачиваться с ручным созданием анимации.

**Спрайтом**

---

**Минусы:**

Нужно создать функцию, которая будет каждый промежуток времени удалять старый спрайт и добавлять новый по тем же координатами.

**Плюсы:**

Вы все придумываете сами. Можете в нужный момент изменить картинку, остановить анимацию и тд.

**Мой совет:**
Делайте спрайтом вручную. Так вы гораздо больше узнаете и получите более качественный результат.

Comment: Спасибо. На gif еще градиенты бьются при анимации. Странно, то почему-то спрайты мало кто использует

Comment: Ленивые все) Но спрайтом более качественно получится. У gif и качество хуже, а спрайтом можно любой формат использовать

Comment: А почему не векторная анимация?

Comment: Можно и векторную анимацию. Прочитать об этом можно здесь: http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/09/20/vector-animations-with-python/